# AngularJS with loading external page with controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a quick question on loading external page with route. I am quite *new* to AngularJS.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
$routeProvider.when('/list', {
    templateUrl: '/list.html'
})
```

Load up the page, but within the list.html there is controller defined.

list.html:

```
<script>
app.controller('test', function(){
    console.log('test');
});
</script>

<div ng-controller="test">

</div>
```

The above code will throw me an error as test is undefined function, unless if i place the `app.controller('test')` to the parent page.

So i can't place controller on external .html files?

Updated link below:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YC6P9W1VfzX8XOyrynCP?p=preview

Comment: move your ctrl definition to seperate js file and include that js file on index.html, then you will be able to place ctrl in template html

Comment: wow really? I will try it out, any reason why? Thanks in advance

Comment: let me know if that works, else setup the plunker to show the problem

Comment: I wouldn't recommend placing your Angular application code in HTML files, it would make it hard to test. However, in your case, your `<script>` snippet should be fine provided that your module definition is included before it.

Comment: @miqid Thanks miqid The only reason i would like to include controller separately just in case if the application gets bigger, not need to load up all the controllers which may not needed for first instance.

Comment: No worries, as long as you're aware of the side effects. Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bCVRjakrVdFbOXtmPeG7?p=preview) to demonstrate what I described.

Comment: @miqid Sorry this is what i mean http://plnkr.co/edit/YC6P9W1VfzX8XOyrynCP?p=preview Clikc on test link

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a separate script.js and should load in main html page during execution of main page or during click of the link

```
    index.html

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="app">
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="testscript.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body ng-controller="home">
        <h1>Hello Plunker! {{change}}</h1>
        <a href="#/test" ng-click="test()" title="Click Test">Test</a>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
      </body>
    </html>

    testscript.js

    function test2($scope){
          console.log('succeed');
    };

    script.js

    // Code goes here
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

    app.controller('home', function($scope){
      $scope.change = "change";  

      $scope.test = function(){
        console.log('clicked');
      }
    });

    app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider.when('/test', {
          templateUrl: 'test.html',
          controller: function(){
            console.log('here');
          }
      })
    });
```